# Extracting shapes from an image using python

Tags: python, image, extract

I wondering what the best way to extract a shape (say some clothes attached) from an image:

[image]

i.e. extracting the pink clothes from this image and making the background appear transparent.

My first thoughts were to read this into a `numpy` array

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
image_name = "image009.png"
img = imread(image_name)
```

then compute a histogram on the RGB data to find the most common colour. I can then presume that this most common colour represents the background, white in this example. I can then make the background transparent thus "extracting" the pink clothes.

However, I obviously this approach would fail if the background **wasn't** the most common colour. Therefore, are there any other solutions or methods people could recommend for achieving this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is background always white?

Comment: @alderven Not always -- I ended up just using the modal value and the MAD to clip the data. Works well enough ...